# Play-Slick how to create play.api.db.Database instance from conf?

Tags: scala, playframework, slick

I'm using Slick 3.1.1 and Play 2.5.10 and have the following `application.conf`:

```
slick.dbs {
  default {
    driver="slick.driver.PostgresDriver$"
    db.driver="org.postgresql.Driver"
    db.url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/exampledb?searchpath=public"
    db.user="postgres"
    db.password="postgres"
  }
  test {
    driver="slick.driver.H2Driver$"
    db.driver="org.h2.Driver"
    db.url="jdbc:h2:mem:test;MODE=PostgreSQL"
    db.username="sa"
    db.password=""
  }
}
```

and to test my Daos I'd like to create a test database using evolutions so I do:

```
package dao

import org.scalatest.BeforeAndAfter
import play.api.db.evolutions.Evolutions

trait BeforeAndAfterDao extends BeforeAndAfter {
  before {
    Evolutions.applyEvolutions("test") // <<< doesn't compile, needs Database instance
  }

  after {
    Evolutions.cleanupEvolutions("test") // <<< doesn't compile, needs Database instance
  }
}
```

but unfortunately I need to create a `play.api.db.Database` to pass to the `apply/cleanupEvolutions`. How can I build the required Database instance from the `application.conf`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can just do it manually in two steps.

**First step:**

I am assuming that you have your `Config` somewhere already so you can just inject it like this:

```
@Inject()(config: Config)
```

if you don't (which you normally always have as most of the times you need to read something from it anyway) you can always expose it as follows (inside your injectable `Module`):

```
bind[Config].to(ConfigFactory.load("application.conf")).in(classOf[Singleton])
```

and then:

```
  val driver = config.getString("slick.dbs.default.db.driver")
  val url = config.getString("slick.dbs.default.db.url")
  val user = config.getString("slick.dbs.default.db.user")
  val password = config.getString("slick.dbs.default.db.password")
```

**Second create your database:**

```
val db = Databases(driver, url, 
    config = Map("username" -> user, 
                 "password" -> password))
```

Comment: Hi Pawel! as always, many thanks you for your help! going throught my `Module` does it mean that I have to have an Application up and running to be able to test my Slick persistence layer? I have been investigating the more lightway Play approach to test: `withDatabase`, `Evolutions`, see here `https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaTestingWithDatabases` but I can't find from there how to then get the `DatabaseConfigProvider` needed for initializing my Slick based DAO's

Comment: Well `DatabaseConfigProvider` is only this:
`trait DatabaseConfigProvider {
  def get[P <: BasicProfile]: DatabaseConfig[P]
}`

Just put an object implementing above trait in your Guice module and you should be fine.

Comment: and here is how to use lightweight injection in tests (without setting up whole Application): https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaTestingWithGuice#guiceinjectorbuilder

Comment: @PawelDolega With Slick I cannot import `Databases` because if comes with 'jdbc', which Slick says we must disable. But the OP uses Slick. How can that work together?

Comment: isn't `Databases` from `Play` world ? (what would you like to achieve btw?)